# Manufacturer tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

We have tags for individual device manufacturers. This makes sense because there is the occasional question that covers multiple/all devices from the same manufacturer.

However, they are often abused and misapplied.

- There's not a tag for the asker's specific device
- The asker didn't see that there is a device-specific tag
- At least one tag is required, so the asker had to add *something*
- etc.

You can help by looking through the questions with these manufacturer tags and

- replacing it with a model-specific tag *where it makes sense*

  - remember: most Android issues are not model-specific; unless it's clear that it's an issue with a specific model don't use the tag
- removing the tag if the question is not about the manufacturer in general
- confirming that it really belongs

Here are the tags with their current question counts

- [samsung](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung) × 527
- [htc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc) × 196
- [lg](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lg) × 100
- [huawei](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/huawei) × 86
- [motorola](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola) × 44
- [lenovo](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lenovo) × 33
- [t-mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-mobile) × 25 (overlaps with [Carrier tag cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/carrier-tag-cleanup))
- [karbonn](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karbonn) × 13
- [dell](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dell) × 4
- [nook](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nook) × 1

Currently unused, but to keep in mind for future checks (picked from existing tags starting with those names):

- [acer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acer)
- [alcatel](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcatel)
- [amazon](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon)
- [archos](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archos)
- [asus](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asus)
- [coby](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coby)
- [logitech](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logitech)
- [micromax](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micromax)
- [nikon](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nikon)
- [nokia](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia)
- [pandigital](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandigital)
- [prestigio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prestigio)
- [sony](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sony)
- [sony-ericsson](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sony-ericsson)
- [toshiba](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toshiba)
- [viewsonic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewsonic)
- [vodafone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vodafone) (overlaps with [Carrier tag cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/carrier-tag-cleanup))
- [zte](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zte)

---

See also:

- [Carrier tag cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/carrier-tag-cleanup)

Comment: I'd say this is a task to repeat in intervals, and we should probably include other manufacturers as well. I just went over "htc to huawei" now, ad did a big roundhouse-kick (re-tagging to the real device, or removing the manufacturer tag completely if unrelated to the issue). Feel free to add more manufacturers for the next run :)

Comment: @Izzy: I agree. What manufacturers should be added?

Comment: Guess you already covered the major ones. For completeness, there's e.g. <del>Sony</del> (has no tag, oops). And, even though not (directly) a device manufacturer, "google" has a similar issue (being used as fallback for everything), so I would include that tag as well. // Let me add some more manufacturers meanwhile; if you disagree with "google", simply remove it afterwards :)

Comment: Well, Google's going to be a special case. It's a manufacturer (sort of), an app developer, and the owner of Android. Virtually every question tagged with `google` should be retagged with something more specific. Perhaps that's a separate tag cleanup project.

Comment: Feel free to edit/move. I feel it a good idea to have everything in one place, as the task is re-occuring regularly (say, we should check every 3 months or the like).

Comment: @Izzy: I moved the carriers to their own cleanup question.

Comment: Good point you linked there. So we can keep this as "master ticket" :) Maybe we should do the same for the "currently unused" watchlist?